# how to run and loop a bash script command form Python script

Tags: python, mongoimport

I have several .json files. I am planing to import those files into MongoDB using this command:

```
mongoimport -h HOSTNAME -d DATABASE -c COLLECTION -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --file FILENAME  --jsonArray
```

But I do not want to do same thing for each file. So I wrote this Python code.

```
import subprocess
import os
import glob

path = ''
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.json')):
    print "currently uploading: " + infile
    p = subprocess.Popen('mongoimport -h HOSTNAME -d DATABASE -c COLLECTION -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --file infile  --jsonArray', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in p.stdout.readlines():
            print line,
    retval = p.wait()
```

on this program,  `infile` is the parameter that gives `mongoimport` command a new JSON file when it loops but I am not able to pass that file name on loop and I cannot use `print infile` with `mongoimport` command.

Could someone please let me know what I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want to put your arguments for the subprocess in a list, otherwise your implementation might be looking for a file with the name of the full string ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)):

```
subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport', '-h', 'HOSTNAME', '-d', 'DATABASE',
                  '-c', 'COLLECTION', '-u', 'USERNAME', '-p', 'PASSWORD',
                  '--file', infile, '--jsonArray'],
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Note the lack of quotes around `infile` to pass the argument.

Alternatively, you can do this in bash directly.

```
for input in *.json
do
    echo "Currently uploading: $input"
    mongoimport -h HOSTNAME -d DATABASE -c COLLECTION \
        -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --file "$input" --jsonArray
done
```

Comment: `shell=True` is unnecessary here, if not outright incorrect.

Comment: In the shell script snippet, you should properly use double quotes around `"$INPUT"` where it is used as a file name argument to `mongoimport`. The code works fine for trivial file names, but has ugly errors when you have a file named literally `*.json` or something.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure about the `shell=True`, but since I was in doubt, I tried to keep it closer to the original code. Thanks for the quotes suggestion too. I have the luxury(?) of mostly working with either files I name or with people that also drop quotes, so that's a bad habit I'll have to drop on this site.

Comment: For total convergence, don't use uppercase for your private variable names. Sorry I forgot to point this out before. Uppercase is reserved for system variables, though it's very common for scripts in the wild to violate this.

Comment: That makes sense. I fixed that too. Thanks again!